# php dynamically generate new web page from link

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

i need serious help here! i have this site am building: a summary of each article is generated from the database with the title as a link, but i want it to be that if someone clicks on the link, a page of the article is automatically generated without hustling; for i cannot code a page for every article i have in the database!
here's my code that generates a summary:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
                $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

                        $search = mysql_query("select * from article 
                        where match(title, body) against('$term') ");

                    if(mysql_num_rows($search)>0){  

                            echo "<div>"."Search Results For: "."<h3><u>".$term."</u></h3>"."</div>";

                            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)){

                                    echo "<div class=\"article\">".

                                    "<div class=\"title\"><a href=\"".$result['cat'].".php"."\">".$result['title']."</a></div>".
                                    "<div class=\"body\">".substr($result['body'], 0, 250)."</div>".
                                    "<div class=\"cat\"><a href=\"".$result['cat'].".php"."\">"."Category: ".$result['cat']."</a></div>".
                                    "<div class=\"author\">"."Author: ".$result['author']."</div>".
                                    "<div class=\"dateTime\">"."Date: ".$result['date']."</div>".

                                        "</div>";
                                }

                    }   


                    else{
                            echo "Sorry! The search for "."<h3>".$term."</h3>"." gave no results.";
                        }

                }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hint: `mypage.com/article.php?id=42` If you don't get it, you need to learn some basics of how to work with PHP. This is one of the most basic use cases for what a web page does.

Comment: man? the reason i ask is that i don't know - for crying out loud! i have read some urlencoding but i seem not to get it. help if you are willing to. thanks

Comment: I'm saying this basic use case is covered in most tutorials or PHP books. You should read more. Here, I found a decent one over at IBM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-blog/section5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each of the articles has its ID. Change the link to go to a dynamic page, passing that ID:

```
"<div class=\"title\"><a href=\"dynamic_page.php?id=$result[id]\">$result[title]</a></div>"
```

Then create a `dynamic_page.php` that accepts that ID and generates the article as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $q = "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `article`
        WHERE
            `id` = '$id'
        LIMIT 1;";
    $q = mysql_query($q);
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
        echo "<div class=\"article\">".
                "<div class=\"title\">".$result['title']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"body\">".$result['body']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"cat\"><a href=\"".$result['cat'].".php"."\">"."Category: ".$result['cat']."</a></div>".
                "<div class=\"author\">"."Author: ".$result['author']."</div>".
                "<div class=\"dateTime\">"."Date: ".$result['date']."</div>".
            "</div>";
    }
    else {
        /* Article not found */
    }
}
```

Note that the `$result['body']` is shown in full this time. Also I suggest using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in your case.

The code is [here](http://pastie.org/private/lyc9gio2xxlpv3dt3schwa)

Comment: Geo, yo the best! long live!

Answer (score 0):

If the link is something like `page.com/article.php?id=20` then your query would look like the following:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Then you can use mysql_fetch_array to display the data.

Comment: Please do not advocate techniques prone to SQL injection. At least point that flaw out, if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: I'm providing an example. I'm not writing a full script.

Comment: You could also use the strategy of PDO combined with bind variables.