# How to separate with (query and php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a post table like this one:

```
id|title|slug|    tags      |
1 |aaaaa|aaaa|cms,php,review|
```

How can I split the "tags" string and make each one into a tag that is clickable like these:

**this is title of post**

this is description of the post

category(blog, internet)

tags(cms, php, review)"each of them will be a link".

Comment: I guess you are looking for the **explode()** function in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php dynamically generate new web page from link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749042/php-dynamically-generate-new-web-page-from-link)

Comment: Sorry, but this question makes no sense to me, even with the pending edit. Please read the [help], especially the page on [ask] a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this using explode

```
   <?php
   $explo_str = explode(',',$tags_string)//tags string is your data straight from the mysql table in this case cms,php,review
   for($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($explo_str) ; $i++)
   {
      echo '<a href="your link">'.$explo_str[$i].'</a>';      
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: @Armen let me know of any problems